# best way to store strings outside of a program?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, io

I'm currently working on a winforms application that gets information from a user via a textbox. Since this information is not likely to change very often, I would like my application to save the input and load it into the appropriate text box the next time it is run.

I feel confident in my ability to set this up on the form side of things, my question has to do with how to store the values outside of the program. My first instinct is to just use a text file, but the overhead needed to handle IO and reading in the values seems a bit much. I also would rather not have the user editing it outside of the textbox in the program. I tried using string resources, but those are read only. Is there a more elegant solution available?

Comment: The simplest would be using text. For more structurized data, consider using XML/JSON. For large data amount and even more complex structure, use Database

Comment: If you are saving the data 'outside' the program then you are going to have to deal with IO - whether it be a file, a database, the registry, etc...

Comment: @JasonBoyd that is true. I'm hoping for a solution similar to resx where the data is easy to access within the program and "ready to go" if you will

Answer (score 0):

You need at least a mediocre database client whether it be sql server, mdf, MS Access, SharePoint, Oracle etc. Sounds like a vis studio prog. (winforms). They are designed for IO procedures but requires data architecture knowledge or relational dbs. (RMDBS).  Try a lightswitch project (if a VS proj.) to get the basics of db and form data relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not outside Your program, but you could try settings, it's easy, kinda like the resources ownly in the settings you can change it.

To change settings goto:
Properties and then double click Settings, here you van add strings, bools etc. Make sure you set them to user
To access them through code use:
Properties.Settings.Default.
To save the settings use:
Properties.Settings.Default.Save()